# Fuelphp: Always load config files

Tags: php, fuelphp

What is the best way to ensure that a config file is always loaded in Fuelphp?

- add to bootstrap?
- Make sure all controllers subclass a parent class
  (or trait) whose before loads it?
- Load it in every class
- Something else

Answer (score 1):

There's a configuration option for this called `always_load`, which is available within `fuel/app/config/config.php`.

> If you want to load 'session' config into a group 'session'
>   you only have to add 'session'. If you want to add it to another group
>   (example: 'auth') you have to add it like 'session' => 'auth'. If you
>   don't want the config in a group use null as groupname.

```
return array(
    'always_load' => (
        'config' => array('session')
    )
);
```

See https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.8/master/config/config.php#L434 and https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/configuration.html